# Finitely generated dense subgroup of an unitary group

Tags: group-theory, unitary-matrices, dense-subspaces

I am interested in finitely generating dense subgroups of the unitary group $U(d)$ of order $d$ (with respect to the operator norm topology), and am considering the following question.

Let $I_d$ be the $d \times d$ identity matrix. Do there exist finitely generated dense subgroups $S_1$ and $S_2$ of $U(d)$ such that for all $g_1 \in S_1 \backslash \{I_{d}\}$ and all $g_2 \in S_2 \backslash \{I_{d}\}$, the matrix $g_1 - g_2$ is invertible?

I feel this should be true because the subgroups $S_1$ and $S_2$ need not overlap, but I am unsure where to start for a proof.

Comment: Could you please clarify what $U(d)$ is? Maybe an open set containing the operator $d$? Also. What is a finitely generated subset? Could it be a finitely generated subgroup? Or a sub-semigroup? With respect to which matrix operation?

Comment: I clarified the question. $U(d)$ is the unitary group, I am looking to generate dense subgroups of $U(d)$ with the above property, and the group operation is matrix multiplication.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but here is a consideration I once applied. If we have some noncommutative divisible ring $D$ of an unitary group and two arbitrary subgroups $A$ and $B$ of $D$, then all non-zero elements of the difference $A-B$ are invertible. Look [here](https://www.mathnet.ru/links/d7a8c9578862a11ea0285d67f04c83d3/sm1970_eng.pdf) maybe it will help you.

Comment: @kabenyuk thanks for the input. Do you perhaps have a more specific link than the one you gave, which merely lands me at a general portal with many different journals to choose from?

Comment: I don't know why the link is messing up.
I think non-commutative divisible rings of characteristic $0$ that are finite-dimensional over their centre and Weyl's unitary trick might help you. An example of using these things can be found [here](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/SM1986v055n01ABEH003004/meta).